# how to receive snmp incoming request using net snmp library

Tags: embedded-linux, snmp, agent, net-snmp, snmpd

I have a project that involves using the SNMP protocol, and I'm using the NET-SNMP library. I have written C code for the client side (manager) of SNMP, and it works perfectly. However, on the server side, I need assistance with receiving SNMP incoming requests using C code and the NET-SNMP library. We are writing a C code for our project. Could you please help me?"

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

netsnmp_session session, *ss;
netsnmp_pdu *pdu;
netsnmp_pdu *response;
oid anOID[MAX_OID_LEN];
size_t anOID_len;
int status;
int count = 0;
int running = 1;

// Initialize the SNMP library
init_snmp("snmpapp");

// Set up the SNMP session parameters
snmp_sess_init(&session);
session.peername = "192.168.100.76";
session.version = SNMP_VERSION_2c;
session.community = "public";
session.community_len = strlen(session.community);

// Open the SNMP session
ss = snmp_sess_open(&session);
if (!ss) {
    snmp_perror("snmp_open");
    exit(1);
}

// Loop to receive and process incoming requests
while (running) {
    pdu = NULL;
    if(!pdu)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // Block until a request is received
    status = snmp_sess_read(ss, &pdu);
    printf("pdu--->Command:%s",pdu->command);
    //printf("status:%d\r\n",status);
    if (status == STAT_SUCCESS && pdu) {
        // Process the request based on its type
        printf("OK\r\n");
        switch (pdu->command) {
            case SNMP_MSG_GET:
                // Process a GET request
                printf("Received GET request\n");
                break;
            case SNMP_MSG_GETNEXT:
                // Process a GETNEXT request
                printf("Received GETNEXT request\n");
                break;
            case SNMP_MSG_SET:
                // Process a SET request
                printf("Received SET request\n");
                break;
            case SNMP_MSG_TRAP:
                // Process a TRAP request
                printf("Received TRAP request\n");
                break;
            default:
                // Unknown command
                printf("Unknown request type\n");
                break;
        }

        // Send a response to the request
        if (pdu->command == SNMP_MSG_GET || pdu->command == SNMP_MSG_GETNEXT) {
            response = snmp_pdu_create(SNMP_MSG_RESPONSE);
            response->errstat = SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
            response->errindex = 0;

            // Add a dummy variable to the response
            anOID_len = MAX_OID_LEN;
            if (snmp_parse_oid(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0", anOID, &anOID_len) == NULL) {
                snmp_perror(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
            } else {
                snmp_add_var(response, anOID, anOID_len, 's', "Hello, world!");
            }

            status = snmp_synch_response(ss, pdu, response);
            if (status != STAT_SUCCESS) {
                snmp_perror("snmp_sess_send_response");
            }
        }

        // Free the request PDU
        snmp_free_pdu(pdu);
    } else {
        //printf("Failed to receive request\n");
    }
}

// Clean up the SNMP session
snmp_close(ss);

// Shut down the SNMP library
snmp_shutdown("snmpapp");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You will only get help if you detail what does not work. Specially with open-source that is already provided and already works.

Comment: @LexLi I have written a code to run this project, which can be seen above. The problem with this code is that it is not receiving the SNMP request such as SET and GET.

Comment: Don’t try to use the manager sample code to perform agent functionality. That’s the wrong approach. The agent is much more complicated to implement.

Comment: @LexLi If possible please give me some more guidance as to exactly what steps I should take